# How to get products outside main loop in Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have this code:

```
add_action('maisvendidos_home', 'maisvendidos_home');

    function maisvendidos_home() {
        $page_id = get_queried_object_id();
        $mais_vendidos = explode("\n", get_post_meta($page_id, 'mais_vendidos', true));
        $mais_vendidos_count = count($mais_vendidos);
        $output = '
            <div class="w-container maisvendidos-container">
            <div class="maisvendidos-txt">Mais vendidos!</div>
            <div class="w-row maisvendidos-row">
        ';
        foreach($mais_vendidos as $produtoID) {
            $produto = wc_get_product($produtoID);
            $produto_img = $produto->get_image(array(200,200));
            $produto_link = post_permalink($produtoID); 
            $output .= '
                <div class="w-col w-col-3 w-col-small-3 w-col-tiny-6 maisvendidos-col">
                    <a href="'.$produto_link.'">'.$produto_img.'</a>
                </div>';
        }
        $output .= '</div>';
        return $output;
    }
```

I called the action in homepage and got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_image() on boolean in

What's wrong here?

Comment: Please at least try to debug your code before asking :(. What is the value of `$producto`, what are the values leading to its calculation. At its current form this is a php debuging question that has little to do with WP or WC

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<?php

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
global $product; 
echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.the_title().'</a><br />';
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Dumping some code is not a valid answer, please edit and explain how or why this code works.

Comment: I think you totally misunderstood the question as your answer is totally wrong as it does not address the question

Comment: I think that the question explains everything by itself: "How to get products outside main loop in Woocommerce?". I paste my code and paste the error message I've got. What else do I have to explain? It's clear and SHAHAB UDDIN was great in his answer. Simple and efficient. Sometimes I think that I would to have a course to learn how to ask in Stack Exchange. I think that these questions don't take anyone to anywhere. But ok, thanks for let me know.